# Different FieldHeaderStyle DetailsView for edit vs readonly mode

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser, detailsview

I'm using an ASP `DetailsView` and would like the item header to be different depending on what mode the `DetailsView` is in.

I have two images - each one is 500px wide and 30px high.  The right 300px is white whereas the left 200px is green or gray, depending on what mode the form will be in (gray for read-only, green for edit).  I want the colored area to be the background of the field headings and the white part of the image to be behind the actual bound data.

Using a skin and some simple CSS, this works perfectly for Firefox (version 21.0):

```
<asp:DetailsView SkinID="DetailsViewSkin" runat="server" CssClass="DetailsView"
  RowStyle-CssClass="DetailsViewRow"
  EditRowStyle-CssClass="DetailsViewRowEdit"
  FieldHeaderStyle-CssClass="DetailsViewHeader"/>

.DetailsView
{
    width: 500px;
}
.DetailsViewRow
{
    background: url('../Images/KL/tableRowGrayjpg') no-repeat #fff;
}
.DetailsViewHeader
{
    width: 200px;
    height:30px;
}
.DetailsViewRowEdit
{
    background: url('../Images/tableRowGreen.jpg') no-repeat #fff;
}
```

The colored area appears behind the headings and the rest overlays the white part of the image.  However, for IE (version 10) and Chrome (version 26.0.1410.64), the background image is appearing in both the `<td>` for the heading and the `<td>` for the values.

Anyone know if this is possible or some cross-browser trick?  Thanks!

EDIT

Here is the html code that is being generated (for a little more clarity).

```
<table id="dvPerson" class="DetailsView" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" rules="all">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="DetailsViewRow">  <!-- DetailsViewRowEdit, when in edit mode -->
      <td class="DetailsViewHeader"></td>
      <td> … </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Firefox only applies `DetailsViewRow` (the css with the image) to the `<tr>` element so the `<td>`'s are left as is, but Chrome and IE apply it to each individual `<td>` element, so that each column has the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this differentiating the [header row](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) `<th>` and `<td>` for the data rows.

```
tr.DetailsViewRow
{
    background: url('../Images/KL/tableRowGrayjpg') no-repeat #fff;
}

tr.DetailsViewRowEdit
{
    background: url('../Images/tableRowGreen.jpg') no-repeat #fff;
}

td.DetailsViewHeader
{
   width: 200px;
   height:30px;
   background: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the generated code only uses `<td>` elements, there are no actual html `<th>`'s - see code added in my edit.  Thanks though!

Comment: I see... the way it's being generated you'll have to match the `<td>`s with class `DetailsViewHeader` and override the CSS properties accordingly. I set `background: none` for the header's `<td>`s. Try this and tell me if this solves the problem.

Comment: Yep - do you know of a way to see a parent element's css style via css?  Now that I think of that, this sounds like a good time to brush up some jquery skills!

Comment: Not that I know of... in CSS there's no way to go up the chain and that's why you have to override the style with `td.DetailsViewHeader`.

Comment: Though the original answer was not perfect, you got me in the right direction - kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  @Leniel helped me get in the right direction.  Based on the html that was being generated (seen below, for brevity), I had to do a little more manual css work:

Generated code:

```
<table id="dvPerson" class="DetailsView" cellspacing="0" border="1" rules="all">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="DetailsViewRow">  <!-- DetailsViewRowEdit, when in edit mode -->
      <td class="DetailsViewHeader"></td>
      <td> … </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

resulting css (works on Firefix, Chrome, and IE)

```
.DetailsView
{
    width: 500px;
}
.DetailsViewHeader
{
    width: 170px;
    height:25px;
}
tr.DetailsViewRow td.DetailsViewHeader
{
    background: url('../Images/KL/tableRowGray.jpg') no-repeat #fff;
}
tr.DetailsViewRowEdit td.DetailsViewHeader
{
    background: url('../Images/KL/tableRowGreen.jpg') no-repeat #fff;
}
```